# Разделение строки на символы и числа Java

Tags: java, строки

Вводится строка такого вида:

```
A1 D1
```

или

```
J7 J10
```

Нужно получить массив, содержащий эти буквы и числа по отдельности, т.е при `J7 J10` должно быть `"J", "7", "J", "10"`.
Скорее всего это нужно делать через `split()`, но я не могу понять, какое выражение писать внутри.

Comment: А если строка A00BB1 22C DD E 33 4?

Comment: Будет вводится только заданная строка, (буква)(цифра)_(буква)(цифра)

Comment: Именно (буква)(число)? Не может быть AA1?

Comment: нет. Только одна буква. Ну а число может быть двузначным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант без регулярок:

```java
String ss = "A5 B7 C11 D777";
String s[] = ss.split(" ");
for(String i : s){
    System.out.println(i.charAt(0));
    System.out.println(i.substring(1));
}
```

Прошу заметить, что сломается на некорректный ввод.

Answer (score 2):

[RegEx](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-v-java) в помощь

```
String f = "f50 t7";
String[] h = f.replace(" ", "").split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(h[i]);
}
```

Вывод

```
f
50
t
7
```

Answer (score -1):

Блин, ну это же простейшее. Появится массив из строк, разделение по пробелу. Вместо пробела вообще любой символ может быть.

```
 S = "5 7";
 S1[] = new String;
 S1 = S.split(" ");
```

Пишу на память, утром откорректирую правильно. Но суть такая